# Interchanging $\Re$ and integral sign

Tags: integration

if a function $f$ is differentiable, and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(t)|^2\,dt<\infty$. Is it true that

$$\Re\left\{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}tf(t)\overline{f'(t)}\,dt\right\}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Re\left\{tf(t)\overline{f'(t)}\right\}\,dt$$
?

Comment: Why would we expect this to be true? Is this just a random problem you pulled out of a hat? Please give some context.

Comment: How do you define the integral of a complex valued function?

Comment: It is just part of some proof I was working on. @PrahladVaidyanathan